# Selecting files to be processed by XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a group of XML files but I want to process only some of them. Not sure this is possible using XSLT, but is there a way to select via the stylesheet which files to process? For instance, I want to avoid creating a copy of files that don't match the XPath expression `//terms:identifier[text()='someID']`.

Sample XML:

```
   <root>
    <wrapper xmlns:terms="http://terms.example.com">
      <terms:trid>somevalue</terms:trid>
      <terms:identifier>someID</terms:identifier>
      <foo:bar>somevalue</foo:bar>
    </wrapper>
   </root>
```

I tried the following but I get empty 'copies' of unwanted files.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//terms:identifier[text()='someID']" />
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: (a) Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? (b) How does the stylesheet know what files are in this "bunch"?

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0 and am running the stylesheet using an Oxygen transformation scenario where folders can be selected as needed.

Comment: If you're using Saxon, then something like `collection('file://my/folder?select=*.xml')` might be the answer?

Comment: Could be. I have used this similarly to [these examples](https://blogs.it.ox.ac.uk/jamesc/2009/02/10/xslt2-collection-with-dynamic-collections-from-directory-listings/) but the problem is--where in a template to select the files with an xpath expression. For instance, can xpath be added in the collection function as part of the filter? I have tried using `collection('file:my/folder?select=*.xml/not(//terms:identifier[text()='someID'])')` with no luck. Also tried setting it as a variable later used to add xpath but still get the unwanted files. I might just filter out files before running XSL.

Comment: You want something like `collection('file:my/folder?select=*.xml')[not(//terms:identifier[text()='someID']‌​)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collection('file:my/folder?select=*.xml')[not(//terms:identifier[text()='someID‌​']‌​)]
```